# Shared Module error while bitbaking recipe

Tags: python-3.x, yocto, dlib

I have created a recipe for the dlib python library
on the python3 setup.py install command the do_install task failed.
(`recipe-sysroot-native/usr/lib/libnsl.so: error adding symbols: file in wrong format`)

Please could anyone help?
Recipe Script:

```
SUMMARY = "A toolkit for making real world machine learning and data analysis applications"
HOMEPAGE = "https://github.com/davisking/dlib"

LICENSE = "Boost-Software"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://dlib/LICENSE.txt;md5=2c7a3fa82e66676005cd4ee2608fd7d2 \
                    file://dlib/external/pybind11/LICENSE;md5=beb87117af69fd10fbf9fb14c22a2e62 \
                    file://dlib/external/libpng/LICENSE;md5=243135ddedf702158f9170807cbcfb66 \
                    file://docs/docs/license.xml;md5=2e6ff4080dcb217d4d300b90e9aabb5b \
                    file://examples/LICENSE_FOR_EXAMPLE_PROGRAMS.txt;md5=57eee82829ed297e23d84de5f905afee \
                    file://examples/video_frames/license.txt;md5=127ee508b60a6be9dea8af3b441993dc \
                    file://python_examples/LICENSE_FOR_EXAMPLE_PROGRAMS.txt;md5=064f53ab40ea2b6a4bba1324149e4fde"

SRC_URI = "git://github.com/davisking/dlib.git;protocol=https"

PV = "1.0+git${SRCPV}"
SRCREV = "3b794540baeabbcd033b544230401967106d5483"

S = "${WORKDIR}/git"

inherit setuptools3 cmake

FILES_${PN} += "/${base_prefix}"

do_install_append() {
        cd ${S}/
        python3 setup.py install
}
```

Comment: Attach the complete error log here.

Comment: Which Yocto Project branch are you using?